# Detect Visual C++ runtime without registry permission

Tags: visual-c++, runtime

I need to find all Visual C++ runtime installed on a machine. The exe will be run by a user who is not in the administrator group.

All solutions I've found rely on registry keys or scanning the c:\Windows folder (which I don't think is very reliable). In addition, if user cannot read the registry, chances are they don't have permission to access the system folder either.

Q1. Is there a 3rd method?

Q2. If multiple versions of VC++ are installed, is there a way to determine which one is used when an application is executed?

Comment: At least for any version of MSVC before VS2010, this is not a question you'd ever want to ask.  There are typically many versions of the same runtime DLL installed in the Windows side-by-side cache, deployed by security updates.  Which one actually gets used depends on the manifest in the program and the installed publisher policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1: Depends on what you mean by "installed".  If you mean "used by some application", then even those methods won't tell you.  If you mean "automatically found during application loading", then you really have to check the registry settings used by the loader.

A2: Sure, check whether the application imports MSVCRT80.DLL or MSVCRT90.DLL, etc.